# Cinema 4D Wind one side force

Tags: graphics, microsoft-dynamics, particles, cinema-4d

is there a way in Cinema 4D to make wind blow in a direction, but not drag in objects at the other side of the fan?

For example, this is what i have now:

```
A --> A     |W=>    B --> B (A,B moves thru the fan in direction of wind)
```

And this is what I want to archieve:

```
A           |W=>    B --> B (A remains stationary, B moves)
```

Thanks for help

Comment: I didn't quite understand it all from your example. Could you expand on that a bit ?

Answer (score 2):

In the *Wind-object*'s settings, go to *Falloff > Form* and set it to **Linear**. The *Wind-objects* appeareance has changed now.

[image: wind-object with linear falloff]

From the *mid-point* to the *arrows end-point*, the falloff will take place. At the end of the *arrow* (i.e. where the arrow's cone is), the *Wind-object* will not have any influence any more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to Cinema atm so i can't confirm this but i belive wind has a falloff you can set to get what you want.